# Random "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping." Error in Automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, automapper-2

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303452/automapper-random-errors/16772435#16772435) for the solution.

> Ok, I finally figured it out. The:
>   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
>   piece of my code sometimes does not get my mapping assembly so while it is  missing I get an error. Replacing this code by forcing the app to find all assemblies solved my problem.

My Entity:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set the name of the Country
    /// </summary>
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set the international code of the Country
    /// </summary>
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set the coordinate of the Country
    /// </summary>
    public Coordinate CountryCoordinate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set the cities of the country
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cities == null)
            {
                _cities = new HashSet<City>();
            }

            return _cities;
        }
        private set
        {
            _cities = new HashSet<City>(value);
        }
    }
```

My DTO:

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public string Lattitude { get; set; }

    public string Longtitude { get; set; }

    public List<CityDTO> Cities { get; set; }
```

My Configuration

```
        // Country => CountryDTO
        var countryMappingExpression = Mapper.CreateMap<Country, CountryDTO>();
        countryMappingExpression.ForMember(dto => dto.Lattitude, mc => mc.MapFrom(e => e.CountryCoordinate.Lattitude));
        countryMappingExpression.ForMember(dto => dto.Longtitude, mc => mc.MapFrom(e => e.CountryCoordinate.Longtitude));
```

In Global.asax Application_Start I have:

```
        Bootstrapper.Initialise();
```

And in Bootstrapper I have:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    private static IUnityContainer _container;

    public static IUnityContainer Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _container;
        }
    }

    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        _container = new UnityContainer();

        _container.RegisterType(typeof(BoundedContextUnitOfWork), new PerResolveLifetimeManager());

        _container.RegisterType<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();  

        _container.RegisterType<ITypeAdapterFactory, AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        _container.RegisterType<ICountryAppService, CountryAppServices>(); 

        EntityValidatorFactory.SetCurrent(new DataAnnotationsEntityValidatorFactory());
        var typeAdapterFactory = _container.Resolve<ITypeAdapterFactory>();
        TypeAdapterFactory.SetAdapter(typeAdapterFactory);

        return _container;
    }
}
```

Where my adapter is:

```
public class AutomapperTypeAdapter : ITypeAdapter
{
    public TTarget Adapt<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
        where TSource : class
        where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TSource, TTarget>(source);
    }

    public TTarget Adapt<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TTarget>(source);
    }
}
```

And AdapterFactory is:

```
    public AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory()
    {
        //Scan all assemblies to find an Auto Mapper Profile
        var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                .GetAssemblies()
                                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Profile));

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var item in profiles)
            {
                if (item.FullName != "AutoMapper.SelfProfiler`2")
                    cfg.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(item) as Profile);
            }
        });
    }
```

So I **randomly** get a "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping." error pointing:

```
    public TTarget Adapt<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TTarget>(source);
    }
```

While this error occurs **randomly** it is hard to debug and see what happens. I have searched a lot with no proper solution.

The error goes like:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Country -> CountryDTO
>   MyApp.Domain.BoundedContext.Country ->
>   MyApp.Application.BoundedContext.CountryDTO
>
> Destination path: List`1[0]
>
> Source value: MyApp.Domain.BoundedContext.Country

My project is an MVC 3 project with Automapper 2.2 and Unity IoC..

I will appreciate any idea, advice or solution and thanks for your answers.

Comment: **[Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153063/2007801)**

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` you would get bit more detailed info:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type

In any case, you have to have mapped all properties of destination model. You were missing CityDTO and Id. Here:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<City, CityDTO>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Country, CountryDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, options => options.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Longtitude, mc => mc.MapFrom(e => e.CountryCoordinate.Longtitude))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Lattitude, mc => mc.MapFrom(e => e.CountryCoordinate.Lattitude));
```

Maybe you would need some additional mapping on City-CityDTO, as you did not specify them.

Comment: Well actually I have written a test with Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<ManagementProfile>());           Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); and everything seems ok.. Also I have mapped city-cityDto already but have not wrote the code piece here as it seems irrelevant to the error, and while my Id is a Guid I do not ignore it in my maps.

Comment: So your entity - Country, has an Id? Then please write exact code that gives you trouble.

Comment: Oh sorry, all entities derives from an abstract EntityBase in which the Id is defined. By the way it seems that I got this error when I change some code and build it while a view is already opened in a browser and after the build I do a F5 refresh.

Comment: A rebuild on the MVC project makes the error gone. May be it is not a big deal but I worry if such an error will raise on production.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error had to do with where I put my `CreateMap<>()` call. I had put it in the static initializer for my DTO. When I moved the `CreateMap<>()` call to somewhere less cute, everything worked fine.