# AutoMapper randomly lose mapping informations

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, mapping, automapper

We have a solution with WCF service getting data from a database with EF 6. Repositories DLL is injected via IoC container. Inside this DLL, you find the entities, context, AutoMapper configuration profiles, etc.

Here's a sample of the SubscriberProfile :

```
public class SubscriberProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            MapDbToDto();
        }

        private static void MapDbToDto()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<SubscriberDb, SubscriberDto>()
                  .ForMember(x => x.FieldA, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Filed123.Valeur))
                  .ForMember(x => x.Contact, opt => opt.Condition(src => !Helpers.IsAllDefault(src.Contact)))
                  .ForMember(x => x.Conjoint, opt => opt.Condition(src => !Helpers.IsAllDefault(src.Conjoint)));
            Mapper.CreateMap<AnotherDb, AnotherDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDb, ContactDto>();
        }
    }
```

And the configuration file that adds the profiles :

```
    public static class AutoMapperRepositoryConfiguration
    {  
        //Create mapings only once
        public static void Configure()
        {
            if (Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().Any())
                return;

            Mapper.Configuration.DisableConstructorMapping();

            Mapper.AddProfile(new ConventionProfile());
            Mapper.AddProfile(new SubscriberProfile());
            Mapper.AddProfile(new BeneficiaryProfile());
        }
}
```

And inside each repo constructor, the Configure method is called, so it gets the mappings :

```
public SubscriberReadRepository(PlansContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            AutoMapperRepositoryConfiguration.Configure();
            _context = context;
        }
```

Everything works just fine, almost all the time. On the server, sometimes, out of nowhere, we get the infamous "**Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping**" error :

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
SubscriberDb -> SubscriberDto
MyRepo.SouscripteurDb -> MyRepo.SubscriberDto

Destination path:
SubscriberDto

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SubscriberDb_0498438FE3D70326924850E4199183EC0EB2AC8DF509202F8CB4EF2D02D9E835 (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
SubscriberDb -> SubscriberDto
MyRepo.SouscripteurDb -> MyRepo.SouscripteurDto

Destination path:
SubscriberDto

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SubscriberDb_0498438FE3D70326924850E4199183EC0EB2AC8DF509202F8CB4EF2D02D9E835
   at MyRepo.SubscriberReadRepository.Get(Int32 idSouscripteur) in e:\BuildAgent\work\9dd90bc72a81e0e3\Sources\MyRepo\SubscriberReadRepository.cs:line 59
   at MyRepo.SubscriberReadServices.Get(Int32 id) in e:\BuildAgent5\work\9dd90bc72a81e0e3\Sources\MyRepo\SubscriberReadServices.cs:line 33
   at WCF.Services.SubscriberServices.Get(Int32 id) in e:\BuildAgen...).
```

Once we get the error, none of the subsequent calls works, they all crash with the same error. We then go to IIS and restart the WCF service and everything goes back to normal. It can work for a few days without problems and then it happens again for no apparent reason. Our DBA assure that no DB modification has been made. Does anyone have an idea ? I checked here and everywhere on Google but couldn't find something random like us. I saw a post here where Jimmy Bogard talks about calling "base.CreateMap" instead on "Mapper.CreateMap" but haven't tried it yet since we don't even know why this bugs happens.

Comment: Your createmap is in a static method. See bottom answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934809/random-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping-error-in-automap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the wrong CreateMap method. Call the base CreateMap method in your Profile class:

```
public class SubscriberProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        MapDbToDto();
    }

    private static void MapDbToDto()
    {
        CreateMap<SubscriberDb, SubscriberDto>()
              .ForMember(x => x.FieldA, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Filed123.Valeur))
              .ForMember(x => x.Contact, opt => opt.Condition(src => !Helpers.IsAllDefault(src.Contact)))
              .ForMember(x => x.Conjoint, opt => opt.Condition(src => !Helpers.IsAllDefault(src.Conjoint)));
        CreateMap<AnotherDb, AnotherDto>();
        CreateMap<ContactDb, ContactDto>();
    }
}
```

And your initialization would be better served with Initialize:

```
public static class AutoMapperRepositoryConfiguration
{  
    //Create mapings only once
    public static void Configure()
    {
        if (Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().Any())
            return;

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();

            cfg.AddProfile(new ConventionProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new SubscriberProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new BeneficiaryProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !  Seems cleaner. Hope it will solve our problems.

Comment: ultraman did this solve your issue? I am facing the same issue but I already do it this way.

Comment: I have the same question.  Did the solution work?  I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @DavidDerman what version of AutoMapper are you using? If you run into the issue again, please raise in the AutoMapper GitHub repo.

Comment: @JimmyBogard - We are using 4.2.1.  Would upgrading to 6.0 solve this issue?  Also, are there any articles about how best to implement automapper in an asp.net application?

Comment: I don't know what issue you're having. Maybe open a GH issue?